# How naniar::impute_below_all() function fills the numbers?

Tags: r, na, missing-data, naniar

Given a simple `df`:

```
library(naniar)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = c(1,NA,2,3,NA,4,5))
```

Please explain me why I get first `NA` to be `0.623` and second `0.504` after running:

```
df %>% bind_shadow() %>% impute_below_all()
```

According to the documentation of

```
naniar::impute_below_all()
```

It says:

> Impute Data With Values Shifted 10% Below Range.

But my range here is 1 to 5. Minimum value is 1 and 10% below it is 1*0.9 = 0.9
Why do I get 0.623 and 0.504.

Can somebody explain this anomaly?

Comment: I think you can check the `getAnywhere('shadow_shift.numeric')` for more info.  I find `x_jitter <- (stats::runif(length(x)) - 0.5) * x_shift * 
            jitter
        x <- ifelse(is.na(x), yes = x_shift + x_jitter, no = x)`

Comment: @akrun you are a professional! I have no words, each time you just impress me with your great knowledge and super informative answers.
Please post as answer

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't tested it.  If you can test it, please post as an answer